# SSH connection will freeze if a certain number of character is displayed

Tags: ssh, freeze

I'm trying SSH from a linux mint 17.3 (client) to a raspberry pi 3 (server), however everytime a certain number of characters is output, for example with commands like `sudo apt-get update` or `ls -al` in a folder with quite some file, the connection will freeze and the only thing I can do is terminate it with the sequence `~.`.

I've already tried several MTU values, as someone suggested in other questions, between 1000 and 2000 (default is 1500), but it didn't work.

I should also mention that the ping is relatively low (about 8-9ms) and the transfer speed is fine as the raspberry is able to hold a sFTP or an apache server without loosing data or disconnecting at all.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but try upping the verbosity on the ssh client too see what it might offer, also, check the /var/logs

```
ssh -vvv rpi3host "touch /tmp/.newer && c=0; while 1; do c=$(expr $c + 1); printf "%5d 1234567890abcde\n" $c; done
```

after you get locked up and reconnect, check the file(s) that were updated

```
find /var/log -newer /tmp/.newer
```

Comment: What is the command "touch /tmp/.newer && c=0; while 1; do c=$(expr $c + 1); printf "%5d 1234567890abcde\n" $c; done" doing?

Comment: 1) touch:: creates a file to use as a reference later by the find command flag `-newer` 2) generating lines of output to try to reproduce a quantifiable number of characters which allegedly is borking the connection.  # each line is 15chrs... so count * 15